# How can I change UITextField leftview frame

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextfield

How can I change the position of the `leftView` in a `UITextField`?

I have tried this, but the `leftView` position does not change

```
UIView *view = [[UIView alloc]init];
[view setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 15, 15)];
[view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[self.urlBar setLeftView:view];
[self.urlBar setLeftViewMode:UITextFieldViewModeAlways];
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

To change the position of the `leftView` you need to create your own subclass of `UITextField` and override the `leftViewRectForBounds:` method to return a different frame.

Answer (score 8):

The following code will give you a padding (displacement) of 20 from left.

```
@IBDesignable
class LeftImageTextField: UITextField {

let displacement: CGFloat = 20

required override public init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    sharedSetup()
}

required public init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)
    sharedSetup()
}

func sharedSetup() {
    self.leftViewMode = .always
    self.leftView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "myImage"))
}

override func leftViewRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect {
    var textRect = super.leftViewRect(forBounds: bounds)
    textRect.origin.x += displacement
    return textRect
}

// placeholder position
override func textRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect
{
    var textRect = super.textRect(forBounds: bounds)
    textRect.origin.x -= displacement
    return textRect
}

// text position
override func editingRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect
{
    var textRect = super.editingRect(forBounds: bounds)
    textRect.origin.x -= displacement
    return textRect
}

override func placeholderRect(forBounds bounds: CGRect) -> CGRect
{
    return bounds
}

/**
 Changes to this parameter draw the border of `self` in the given width.
 */
@IBInspectable
var leftImage: UIImage? {
    didSet {
        self.leftView = UIImageView(image: leftImage)
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Solution for **iOS 13** on **Swift 5**:

```
let padding: CGFloat = 8
let outerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: padding * 2 + 23, height: 23))
let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: padding, y: 0, width: 23, height: 23))
imageView.image = image
outerView.addSubview(imageView)
leftView = outerView // Or rightView = outerView
leftViewMode = .always // Or rightViewMode = .always
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to make sub class.

```
UIView *leftView2 = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, self.yourTextField.frame.size.height)];
leftView2.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
self.yourTextField.leftView = leftView2;
self.yourTextField.leftViewMode = UITextFieldViewModeAlways;
```

Comment: I believe that with iOS 13 this is no longer correct. At least it works for iOS 12 but not 13.

Answer (score 1):

For iOS 13 you can **add** these lines (they should have no impact on pre-13)

```
view.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(15).Active = true;
view.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(15).Active = true;
```

This is Xamarin code but I guess you should be able to translate it to Swift/ObjectiveC.